# Flash / Actionscript: How to insert images in dynamic text (In line image)?

Tags: image, flash, actionscript, inline

I want to insert images in dynamic-text-box(s) which should be inline.
**Detail:**
I am preparing an application using flash CS4; The application is just like a chat room which will show conversation the only difference in this; it will show stored messages (stored in XML file). I want to insert smiling faces (emotions) in text body (using html tags) but the problem is that image is not inline (like in chat room [yahoo, hotmail, etc.]).
I have no idea what to do......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its good to get the solution of my problem but sad I got solution by myself :-P
The simplest solution I got is, to update my Flash CS4 to Flash CS6; in Flash CS6 text (TextField) have extra feature like TLF (Text Layout Framework). By use TLF I can insert graphics in text area and inserted graphics are inline as well.
Problem Solved :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please paste your code where you set the dynamic-text-box.text

Make sure that you wrap the whole text in html braces, not only images.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed images in any HTMLText field using the  tag. 
The image, however, must be loaded externally. You can't get images stored in your library.

Comment: For the record, although I don't think it is the answer to the problem in this question - regarding "you can't get images stored in your library", you actually can use library item identifiers as src in img tags in HTML in TextFields. http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?326531-lt-img-gt-from-Library-in-textField&p=2505774#post2505774 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068933/using-symbol-from-library-in-htmltext-img-tag-in-actionscript-3